# Gmail problems in nokia 1520

Tags: email

I am very disappointed with the oficial gmail in my Nokia 1520.

When I forward message i need previously open the attachements like  pictures or document otherwise do not appear the attachement to the mail I send. 
Second question is about the text i want to forward if I need to delete all or part of them is totally imposible . 
Please help me

Pascual

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no official Gmail app on Windows Phone. Did you add it as a regular mail account to the system?

Comment: Please post 2 issues as 2 different questions.

Comment: @Pascual, the title is very bad for this question.

Answer (score 1):

From the question its not clear if you added a mail account to the default Mail app. If yes, I don't think there is any such issue.

Also there are no official apps from Google. What you might have downloaded is an app offered by another developer who mostly might have exposed a Web page from the app.

The best way to use Gmail is from the Browser. You can pin the website on your start screen and this will start acting like your "App" (without the necessary notifications).

Answering your second question about editing SMS when forwarding - when you forward a message, you do get an text box where you should be able to select/add/modify/delete existing message content. Check out the steps here - http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/people/send-a-text-message